# What happened to the "Apply to" feature on product attributes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

In Magento 1, product attributes have a setting called "Apply to" where you can set the product types for which the attribute will be visible (simple, configurable, etc).  However, I don't see it anywhere in Magento 2.

[image: Magento 1 Product Attribute - "Apply to" field]

Comment: Interesting hadnt seen that one yet. Why is there no more validation on product type level? ----- als we have seen that an "APPLY TO" for non-visible and frontend-visible (catalog/search) differing between these 2 types would make a lot more sense ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 2, no more that great feature! I don't understand why they can remove that feature, but it is the truth.

Anyway, there is a great & FREE extension to get that feature back into your system. Please check it at https://belvg.com/blog/big-day-release-apply-to-attribute-option-free-for-magento-2-0.html