# Adding custom product attribute properties in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, admin, attributes, bug

**How to add custom product attribute properties in admin for admin?**

> - Magento2 has removed attribute filter to product type.
> - So,in frontend layer-navigation I'm getting attribute filter of it's child    product also for bundle and configurable product in
>     category page.
> - I want to add 'Apply To' property when i create new attribute.
> - When I'm creating attribute I want to set scope for product type as    we were did in magento1.

[image]

Anyone know how can I do this?I [found something](https://spaggel.nl/magento-2/extending-magento-2-eav-attributes/) which may help.

Comment: share the code which you used to create attribute?

Comment: i have show in link,but i want also when admin create from backend

Answer (score 2):

You used attribute code like below.
Into code we need to add field

> 'apply_to'

and into that you need to specify types of product for which you used above attribute. Here I create attribute only for Simple, Group and Bundel type of product.

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'myattribute',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'My Atrribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'apply_to' => 'simple,grouped,bundle'
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Yes,but it not solved my problem I want to remove all child-product's attributes from bundle/configurable category page in layered navigation filter

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, there is no option to choose a specific product while creating product attribute.

Easy for your reference: [What happened to the "Apply to" feature on product attributes in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167040/what-happened-to-the-apply-to-feature-on-product-attributes-in-magento-2)

You can achieve this in two ways.

**By creating attribute via setup script:**

If you want to create a custom attribute for a specific product type, we can use the setup script `apply_to` parameter.

Easy for your reference: [Magento2 custom attribute for specific product type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182710/magento2-custom-attribute-for-specific-product-type)

**By direct mysql qurey:**

If you want to change the admin created custom attribute, we can directly change the `apply_to` in the database by using the below query.

Note: `apply_to` default value is `NULL`.

> update catalog_eav_attribute set apply_to="simple" where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code="test");

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes,but it not solved my problem I want to remove all child-product's attributes from bundle/configurable category page in layered navigation filter