# Product attribute apply_to all product type

Tags: attributes

I have an attribute (body_fit) present only for a simple product, now I need this attribute present for virtual and configurable products.

1. How I can change this configuration?
2. What happens if I change this option via PHPMyAdmin?

I have 600 products with this attribute set.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: i am not sure but try this query `update catalog_eav_attribute set apply_to="simple,virtual,configurable" where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code="test");

`

Comment: Many thanks @MohitPatel works perfectly!

Comment: I have add answer??? Your accept this question answer???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query your database :-

```
update catalog_eav_attribute set apply_to="simple,virtual,configurable" where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code="test");
```

And get more information refer this link ---

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/239535/85907**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...